# Why is Google analytics not verifying my tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

I have pasted the script that Google provided as below on every page of my website.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-65079904-3', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

However Google is not verifying my tracking code.

Here is my Screenshot:
[image]

Why can Google Analytics not verify my tracking code?

Comment: Niyat, how long has it been since you inserted the code? It may take up to 24 hrs for GA to catch up

Comment: It has been 24 hours already! and also google showing that last checked at #time. But it still not verifying my code.

Comment: Do you see any traffic in real time?

Comment: Everything looks fine. I can see pageview and event hits going through. You may also want to install Google Debugger so that you can verify the hits being sent.